# How does MbUnit work with VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tdd, mbunit, gallio

I set up MbUnit and have been trying to get it to work with VS 2008 using the MbUnit GUI but every time I run a test it closes and I get a this program needs to close error.

I had a similar problem with Gallio where I got a runner exception every time I ran a test.

Do I need an addin for VS like testDriven.Net to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Same here. TestDriven.Net really makes things slick and easy. Right-click on a test and run it... MBUnit integrates fine with that add-in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need TestDriven.Net but it sure helps.

When you say you use the MBUnit GUI "but every time I run a test it closes..." do you mean that MBUnit closes or VS2008?  If is MBUnit, then perhaps there is something wrong with your installation.  If it is VS2008, then something is fishy since MBunit shouldn't cause VS2008 to crash.

I've used (though I've stopped and now use NUnit) MBUnit with TestDriven.Net and VS2005 with great success.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend testdriven.net for a free tool, and ReSharper as a better tool for running MbUnit tests.

The Gallio test running shouldn't be crashing on you like that, there is a problem somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using combination of Visual Studio 2008, ReSharper 4.1 and latest builds of Gallio. With that it works pretty well.